# Non working microphone with smartphone headset

Tags: 12.04, sound, microphone, headset

I plugged in my Samsung smartphone headset on my Lenovo Thinkpad W520 and although the sound that comes out from the earbuds works properly it seems that the microphone is not working at all.I looked around the laptop in case there is a dedicated port for microphone,but I noticed that the headphones port is also the port for the mic as well.In the Sound settings it shows the mic of the headset,but when I say something to test the mic it doesn't show any reaction at the sound bar on the bottom of the Sound Settings window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alsa-Mixer is the solution to the problem.
After I installed it I raised the volume on the `Dock Mic` (the first one that says `Dock Mic`) and it worked.

Comment: Might you provide an example of your use of alsamixer?